# XML Layout: how can we make an xml layout like this Duolingo app

Tags: android, android-layout

I am a beginner in Android. So, I want to know how can an xml layout be achieved like this in the picture.

[image]

Comment: what you have tried ??

Comment: I did not try it myself because I did not understand where to start from. I was dangling between using FrameLayout and Relativelayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the code of what you want..

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="#CDDC39"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:background="#F8BBD0"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:background="#727272"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:background="#212121"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:background="#E91E63"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#795548"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

just copy whole code in your xml file and you will know.. and change by your requirement. now you can add textview, imageview, button and else inside particular layout. this is all about layout-weight attribute.. try to understand my code.  and if you dont know about anything than try to write each layout line by line and you will know how its work..

Comment: Thank you so much for the trouble.

Comment: Yes, I understand it very well. You have used nested LinearLayouts. Great

Comment: Could you please suggest me some cool fonts that I could download for free and use in my Android projects?

Comment: there is no cool font use roboto. this is google font. and its best.. each n every lollipop and higher device have this font.